# possibility of trisection of angles

Tags: geometry, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

i know that  $\frac{\pi}{7}$ can be trisected if and only if $4x^3-3x-cos( \frac{\pi}{7})$ is reducible over $\mathbb {Q}$$(cos\frac{\pi}{7}) $.

but i don't know how to check this.

help pls.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

By playing a bit with the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$, we have that $\cos\frac{\pi}{n}$ is an algebraic number of degree $\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. This gives that $\cos\frac{\pi}{21}$ has degree $6$ and $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$ has degree three over $\mathbb{Q}$. The roots of $$T_3(x)-\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$$
are $\beta=\cos\frac{\pi}{21},\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{21}+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{-\beta+\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{2},\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{21}+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{-\beta-\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}{2}$, or $\cos\frac{\pi}{21},\cos\frac{5\pi}{7},-\cos\frac{8\pi}{21}$. Since $\cos\frac{5\pi}{7}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$ due to
$$\cos\frac{5\pi}{7}=T_5\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\right),$$
in $\mathbb{Q}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\right)$ we can find $\beta$ and $T_8(\beta)$ by solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: thanks!but i didn't completely understand u.what's$T_n(x)$?

Comment: @user115608: T_n(x) is the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind: $$T_n(\cos\theta) = \cos(n\theta).$$